# Rails 4 + MongoDB + Search query LIKE does not give correct output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

In Rails, I am trying to fetch data from mongodb using LIKE query by providing regular expression but even though not getting the correct output.

Model : User

```
_id, name, display_name, age, address, nick_name
a1, Johny, Johny K, 12, New York, John
b1, James, James Waltor, 15, New York, James
c1, Joshua, Joshua T, 13, California, Josh
```

Now I have 3 set of records.

Query 1 : Search User having 'Jo' as keyword in initial name

```
User.where(name: /^jo/i)
```

Output - Only One record - instead of two.

Query 2 :- Match the text with all column values

```
User.where($where: /^jo/i)
```

Not getting the proper output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok on the Query 1, can you output the documents. I believe one of your records in 'name' has a character in front of it such as white space. I just run the same query locally and it pulled multiple records back.

Try this:
`User.where(name/(.*)jo(.*)/i).count` and see what that returns. It should match 2. If that works, then you'll need to look at what is incorrect with the store value.

On Query 2, where have you seen this syntax. The [$where](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) is expecting a string of a js function to execute to match records. In your case to match any field within the document with an expression you would need to do a recursive function across each field in each document.

Answer (score 0):

For Query 2 to match against all fields
One solution, although inefficient, is to do it within the Rails app instead of Mongodb query.

e.g.
`User.all.select do | user | user.attributes.values.grep(/^jo/i).any? end`